# changing brightness of QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

i have a an QGLWidget that I am trying to adjust the brightness of using a slider widget however im running into trouble trying to get my head around how I would go about doing this.

I know that I need to move the pixels from the frame buffer to a matrix so I can make the needed adjustments but im not understanding how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup a custom `slot` for your `QGLWidget` which typically would involve making a custom class that inherits from `QGLWidget` with the added functionality of the additional `slot`.

So let's say that you define that as:

```
public slot:
    void foo(int value);
```

You need to `connect` `foo` to one of your `QSlider`'s signals: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#signals Let's say you have access to  `QSlider bar` in your `QGLWidget` specialization, then you could do this in the constructor:

```
connect(&bar, &QSignal::valueChanged, this, &foo);
```

This connection will cause `foo` to be called every time the `bar.valueChanged` signal is called. For a more in depth example of signals and slots with a `QSlider` you can look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-sliders-example.html

**EDIT:**

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what a `QGLWidget` is it does not have "pixels". It has OpenGL Objects. After updating the OpenGL Object you can call [`paintGL`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#paintGL) to force your specialization of the `QGLWidget` to redraw.

All that to say, what you're trying to ask here is: **"How do I redraw an OpenGL Object with another color?"**

You need to provide more information in your question before I can answer that. In the simplest case you could just call [`glColor`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColor.xml) to accomplish this. If that's your case you will probably find this link helpful: [glColor not actually changing OpenGL's color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8315809/2642059)

In the more in-depth case such as situations where you're ignoring a OpenGL object's color you might be able to add a black polygon right in front of the camera and change it's transparency in `foo`. Having this draw to the color buffer but not the depth buffer could be enough, though with more complex obscuring shaders you might have to put in some additional work.

Though I think these examples still use a `QGLWidget`, instead of a `QOpenGLWidget`, they may be helpful to you in understanding how to work with OpenGL via Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html

Comment: I know how the connect works what im asking is how to move the widget from the frame buffer to a matrix, QGLWidget does have a direct method for accessing pixels like QImage does

Comment: So if I were to retrieve the pixels of the open gl objects is there a function I can call for that? I know I may not be going about this the most efficient or easiest way but thats what the professor is asking for.

Comment: @BKreger I've added a link to some Qt/OpenGL examples in my answer. Let me just stress again, you're looking for "pixels" but that is like asking what the best way to take your goldfish for a walk is. Try understanding the examples, then if my answer doesn't contain enough to get you going lets talk again.